# How do I post a story to wall using Graph API in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, facebook

How can I publish a story on the wall of the user?I have already authenticated user using oAuth I am able to publish it on wall.But I want show a dialog before posting asking for user's permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to simply post to a social networks wall is to use sharekit http://getsharekit.com/

However if you need to post to another users wall you will need to get their facebook id
then to post to their Facebook you need to call the feed api with correctly encoded contents

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"[friend_ID]/feed" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`